# apsx-page will not work. error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

I have an aspx.page that i made in visual studio. When I debug it for the program it works fine, but when I try to open it in Google Chrome I get this message:

> error on line 1 at column 2:  StartTag: invalid element name

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

the page I try to run is located here:

file:///C:/Users/Yngvild/Desktop/Visual%20Studio%202015/WebSites/oppgave/InnUtlogging.aspx

And here is the code for the first line in the aspx-file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="InnUtlogging.aspx.cs" Inherits="InnUtlogging" %>
```

What can I do?
I tried to install ASP.net in the control panel but it didn't work

Comment: what about this issue? Would you please share us the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> the page I try to run is located here: file:///C:/Users/Yngvild/Desktop/Visual%20Studio%202015/WebSites/oppgave/InnUtlogging.aspx

You're trying to open an `.aspx` page directly from the file system.  So the very first tag is invalid HTML:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="InnUtlogging.aspx.cs" Inherits="InnUtlogging" %>
```

ASP.NET is a *server-side* framework.  It has to be executed in the context of a web server to which the browser will make requests.  When you debug in Visual Studio, you are provided with a debugging web server instance.  In a Release scenario, you need to deploy the application to a web server (a local instance of IIS will do just fine).

There are a variety of ways to deploy to a web server.  [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) looks like a good place to start.

Comment: Now I have installed IIS but it still doesn't work!?! I get the same error? Do I have to publish the site in Visual Studio?

Comment: I am going to send the whole project to another person by zipping and the other person will have to unzip it and then open the pages by right-clicking and open them in a browser. Do I have to do anything? Or is it that person who has to install IIS and so?

Comment: @YngvildDahlBrenna: If you're still trying to open the file from the file system then, yes, you'll still get that error.  You have to publish the website to a web server (in this case IIS).  Server-side code *does not run* in the browser, at all.

Comment: @YngvildDahlBrenna, I got the same result as yours,  like David's suggestion, if you want to visit it, you need to really publish it to the server or just visit/run the project locally with the VS IDE. See: https://forums.asp.net/t/1717390.aspx?Publish+error